# Python Looping Entire Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I can't seem to find out how to do this after much searching.

Dict:

```
mdr = {'main': {'sm': {'testm': {'test1': 'test', 'test2': 'test'}}, 'lm': {}, 'l': {}}}
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
-Main
--SM
---Testm
----Test1:Test
----Test2:Test
--LM
--L
```

I **won't** know the exact amount of sub-directories it will process so I need to make a loop that will go through the entire direct. I only know how to display the whole directory if I know how far the dictionary goes. I would like it to display all possible keys if possible.

Comment: Executing the line gives me a SyntaxError. Could you please check your dictionary again?

Comment: @Xaranke Updated, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think recursion is a better bet than a loop. This is pretty close.

```
def print_dict(d, current_depth=1):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print '-' * current_depth + str(k)
            print_dict(v, current_depth + 1)
        else:
            print '-' * current_depth + str(k) + ':' + str(v)
```

Output (after fixing the syntax of your dictionary):

```
>>> print_dict(mdr)
-main
--lm
--l
--sm
---testm
----test1:test
----test2:test
```

The case is off from your desired output, but you should be able to handle that. If you want to preserve the original order, then you need to use an `OrderedDict` instead of a `dict`. `dict` is a hash table, so it could do anything with the order. (Luckily, the `isinstance(v, dict)` test still works on `OrderedDict`.)

Comment: Do you know how the print's would be in Python 3.x?

Would it be like this: `print('-' * current_depth + str(k))`

Comment: Yeah. Should just be added parentheses for `print` in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I can't believe it was as simple as calling the function again. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

```
def tree(data, indent=0):
    if isinstance(data, basestring):
        print '{i}{d}'.format(i='-'*indent, d=data)
        return
    for key, val in data.iteritems():
        if isinstance(val,  dict):
            print '{i}{k}'.format(i='-'*indent, k=key)
            tree(val, indent + 1)
        else:
            print '{i}{k}:{v}'.format(i='-'*indent, k=key, v=val)

tree(mdr)
```

Output:

```
main
-sm
--lm
--testm
---test1:test
---test2:test
--l
```

Input from the console (in response to the comment on this answer):

```
>>> mdr = {'main': {'sm': {'testm': {'test1': 'test', 'test2': 'test'}, 'lm': {}, 'l': {}}}}
>>> def tree(data, indent=0):
        if isinstance(data, basestring):
            print '{i}{d}'.format(i='-'*indent, d=data)
            return
        for key, val in data.iteritems():
            if isinstance(val,  dict):
                print '{i}{k}'.format(i='-'*indent, k=key)
                tree(val, indent + 1)
            else:
                print '{i}{k}:{v}'.format(i='-'*indent, k=key, v=val)

>>> tree(mdr)
main
-sm
--lm
--testm
---test1:test
---test2:test
--l
>>>
```

Comment: I get `NameError: global name 'tree' is not defined`, and the output is in the same order as my answer, not what you have above.

Comment: I added the console i/o to the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. The braces are different in your example. Note that `lm` and `l` are more indented `sm` in your output. The original dictionary had some syntax errors; try it with the most recent one.

Comment: Going off the updated mdr, it's because `dict` order isn't kept. In the console do `>>> mdr = {'main': {'sm': {'testm': {'test1': 'test', 'test2': 'test'}}, 'lm': {}, 'l': {}}}` and then `>>> mdr` The order is not kept. One would have to use `collections.OrderedDict` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You should show what you have tried.

Regardless, I thought it was a fun project.  What do you think of my solution? It doesn't include the unexpected caps that are in your preferred result.  But, then, how can you expect the unexpected?

```
def dict_tree(d, i = 1):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print '-' * i + key
            dict_tree(value, i + 1)
        else:
            print '-' * (i + 1) + key + ':' + value
```

Should output:

```
-main
--lm
--l
--sm
---testm
-----test1:test
-----test2:test
```

Comment: Same thing I have been seeing all day long :). What do you mean unexpected caps? Also, as for showing what I tried I didn't even know how to try. Thank you!